# What is the best way to check if http GET response content is valid with?

Tags: bash, rest, http, get, wget

I want to check that i got all the content and not just a part of it. If the http header is OK, does it mean that all the content is also OK?

So far i have been using Bash and wget command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for status code 200. According the W3's documentation, status code 200 received in response to a GET requests means the request succeeded and the response is and is returned in the response.

Someone could write an API that returns garbage and still sends status code 200. If you are just getting a file/document from a Web server, then the status codes are probably very trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a look at the response body to check all your content is there you could use tools like Fiddler or IExplorer F12, wireshark. As @ahoffer mentions if status is 200 ok then the server is giving you what you requested.